# add a menu to a user menu

Tags: 7, routes

I'm defined a menu with a hook_menu, but he appears in navigation menu.
how do I put in the user menu?

```
$items['budget/view'] = array(
    'title'             => t('Ver gastos'),
    'description'       => 'Veja quanto é que anda a gastar',
    'page callback'     => 'page_budget_view',
    'page arguments'    => array(2,3),
    'access callback'   => ($user->uid > 0),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `'menu_name' => 'primary-links';` in your code and of course you have to alter the `primary-links` to the menu of your choice.

```
$items['budget/view'] = array(  
  'title'             => t('Ver gastos'),  
  'description'       => 'Veja quanto é que anda a gastar',  
  'page callback'     => 'page_budget_view',   
  'page arguments'    => array(2,3),   
  'access callback'   => ($user->uid > 0),  
  'menu_name'         => 'primary-links',  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For user menu you should use this

```
'menu_name' => 'user-menu',
```